# How To Restore Android OpenGL Native App

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es, android-ndk

I have an Android app that renders an OpenGL scene.  All of the OpenGL code is done in c++.

The problem I am having is that when I press the home button, and then return to the app, the OpenGL calls start to return errors.

Specifically, the ES 1.1 version fails on `glDrawArrays` with a logcat error `<gl_draw_error_checks::550>: GL_INVALID_OPERATION`

The ES 2.0 version fails on `glUseProgram` with a locat error of `<core_glUseProgram:1496>: GL_INVALID_VALUE`.

What is the proper process for leaving / returning to an OpenGL ES application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So ultimately i fixed this issue by following some sample code in this [book](http://www.packtpub.com/android-native-development-kit-cookbook/book).  In chapter 4, they have a sample that does all the egl calls in c++.  So using that method i was able to create my own context and manage its lifetime rather than having the GLSurfaceView manage the lifetime.

Basically, I create a single context that is never destroyed.  Then when the surface goes away, i simply call `eglMakeCurrent( display, NULL, NULL, NULL )` and stop my render loop, and when the surface is restored I make the context current with the new surface.  This works fine and I have no more crashes and don't have to reload my shaders or geometry everytime the app is backgrounded or screen is rotated.

Answer (score 0):

eglContext is likely to be destroyed when App paused.but there are a method provided by GLSurfaceView called [setPreserveEGLContextOnPause](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html#setPreserveEGLContextOnPause%28boolean%29).

you can also refer to the [discuss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112768/prevent-onpause-from-trashing-opengl-context).

Comment: Thanks, but this method is not available in the 2.3 api which I have to support

Comment: so maybe you should recreate shaders and programs.